# Why does iter() require & for lambda functions, whereas range doesn't in this example

Tags: rust

> Note: question and answer predate Rust 1.0. The equivalent to `range` in Rust 1.x is the half-open range syntax `..` to produce a value of type `std::ops::Range`.

I have some trouble understanding the differences in this example:

I thought that both `range(..)` and `iter()` are `std::iter::Iterator`
So why can I pass `|x|` in the first example to `map` and `filter`, but have to pass it as `|&x|` in the 2nd example?

```
use std::iter::AdditiveIterator;

fn main() {
    let range1 = range(1,9);
    let range2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    //indented for easier visualization
    let sum1 = range1       .map(| x| x * x).filter(| x| x % 2 == 0).sum();
    let sum2 = range2.iter().map(|&x| x * x).filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0).sum();

    println!("{}", sum1);
    println!("{}", sum2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just knowing they're both `Iterator` without knowing `Iterator`s type parameter doesn't tell you anything about what they're iterating over, which is the important difference here. For this code:

- `range1` is an `Iterator<int>`
- `range2.iter()` is an `Iterator<&int>`

That is, [slice iterator](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/slice/struct.Items.html) returns references pointing directly into the slice (it has to do this or, for general `T`, it would be trying to steal ownership out of a borrowed slice `&[T]`: illegal), while `range` just returns the counter by-value since it constructs it internally, and is free to hand it out ("transferring ownership").

Hence, to get an `int` out of the slice iterator, you need to dereference the reference somehow, e.g. pattern matching through it via `|&x| ...`, or writing `|x| *x * *x`.